# I am building an ios navigation app that is not opening in the ios simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have this navigation app with several views and no data yet.. however I had a small break from coding over the weekend and have come back to it only to have it not load in the ios simulator.

There are no errors in the xcode output while it runs but as soon as i click to run button it loads the app up but as soon as it opens it closes and goes to the home screen.

I have tried cleaning the build and opening closing everything but just cannot figure this thing out...

Comment: Too little information. What does the console say? Did you reset the simulator?

Comment: console shows no error, just says the usual thing that it says when it starts any app. Also just checked another app and thats not opening either so its not the code its the simulator.. I will look at how to reset it now.

Comment: Two system restarts later plus everything else in between that I could think of doing and suddenly its working again.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no error messages or indication as to what is wrong I am going to suggest
a few other things you can try out:

Have you tried "iOS Simulator" -> "Rest content and settings".

In Xcode click the "Product" menu in the menubar, hold down the Option key and
you should see "Clean" change to "Clean Build Folder".

Lastly pull up Organizer (Shift+Command+2), select the "Projects" and the then click "Delete Derived Data".

The two last ones should not be directly related to the simulator, but they won't hurt either.

Comment: I have tried all of the above and still no luck. It just started this morning from no where there are no errors being generated in the console it just starts the simulator up the app loads a black screen then closes and shows the icon screen of the simulator.. Im going to try restarting the computer and see if that dose anything.

Answer (score 0):

Does your app requires internet connection to run.. if it does, check ur internet connection as well.

I have this kind of problem last time and turn out, if there's no internet connection and you didn't put any exception on that, the app will straight away crash with no errors..

Comment: No this particular application dosn't. Thankyou for the post though as I think I have also had the same thing happen to me on another application in the past.